# In an AWS Step Function's Parallel state, if one branch fails is there a way to ensure that the other branches continue until completion?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

I have a step function with a parallel state that has four branches (A, B, C, D) each with 3 Glue StartJobRun task states. In the case that branch A fails during the 1st task, how can I make sure the other branches continue with their tasks as long as they are successful?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in AWS Step Functions if one branch fails, the other branches will be immediately terminated and their results ignored. Step Functions will make a best-effort attempt to cancel any .sync tasks that are in progress, and stop executing any further states on any branch.
If you want to let those other branches proceed to completion, you have to prevent any branch from failing. You can use Catch blocks on each state and transition to a Succeed (even when it was actually a failure). Then, after the Parallel completes, add a new state to do error handling to check which branches succeeded or failed.

Comment: The catch block is not working for me, the Parallel step is failing anyway. Any other ideas?

Comment: Share your ASL please. Let's see your definition.

Comment: Thanks, @pooya I resolved the issue. The problem was that in the Parallel step i have 5 branches each with 3 steps. And on every step, I have catch block except on the leaves (last steps in the branch) AWS does not allow that. So my last function was actually exiting with error and causing the whole step to fail. In the graph, you cannot see that it says canceled, but i found in the logs the errors. So the last step (its lambda function) i make sure always returns success. Thanks again